# Which is better to use: regex.containsMatchIn(String) or String.contains(regex) and why?

Tags: regex, kotlin

If i have a String called "text" and a Regex (called "regex" for ease) i want to check it against, should i use:

```
regex.containsMatchIn(text)
```

or should i use:

```
text.contains(regex)
```

Both seem to be successful but i am unsure of the best practices concerning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whichever one makes your code easier to read. There is no difference between them because `text.contains(regex)` calls the `regex.containsMatchIn(text)` As per [`Strings.kt` source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Strings.kt):

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun CharSequence.contains(regex: Regex): Boolean = regex.containsMatchIn(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin documentation says:

**contains**

> Returns true if this char sequence contains the specified other sequence of characters as a substring.

**containsMatchIn**

> Indicates whether the regular expression can find at least one match in the specified input.

It looks like both do pretty much the same thing, so functionally it doesn't matter too much which you use.

However, since you're dealing with regex, I feel like using `containsMatchIn` is more appropriate since it's part of the regex library and intended for that purpose specifically.

Where `contains` can be used for more than just regex, e.g. for finding if 'flow' is a substring of 'overflow'. So, it's likely less appropriate to use it for regex, if we're being picky.